# Chrome on Android 6: Why are those images not shown?

Tags: android, html, css, google-chrome, flexbox

The website I made for my client has some weird image issues on his Android Tablet.
I can't reproduce the issue on my devices or in any browser.

The website in question: https://www.service-center-hamburg.de/

The issue at hand: (The images should not be cropped like this)
[image: The issue at hand: The images are not being shown correclty]

Here the images are not shown at all:

[image: Images not shown at all]

My client has a Android 6 Tablet with the latest Chrome Browser with no Browser Extensions.
It can't be Wifi related or a router/firewall settings issue because he told me some of his customers have the same problem.

[image]

I suspect a weird chrome/android 6 issue with flexbox css... but I am rather lost, right now.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I managed to fix this issue.

The problem was solved by removing the border radius from the images.